# Asp Session cookie lost on postback

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies, session-state

The session state cookie is lost on postback on some devices e.g. ios-12

Any way to force the cooke to be included

On the same device the cookie is included in the request object for GET just not on POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to be an issue with the certificate

We had a wildcard certificate, adding the proper domain name to the cert has resolved the issue for ios 12